# FinishedLaunching override?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

In Monotouch, there is an override for FinishedLaunching... what is the equivalent in Obj-C?

Answer (score 2):

In your AppDelegate object implemetation:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `(UIApplication *)application` not notification

Comment: But the apple page says NSNotification: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW3

Answer (score 1):

The applicationDidFinishLaunching: method of the NSApplication delegate will be called when the app has finished loading.

Many of the default project templates provided by Xcode set up an NSApplication delegate for you. For instance, if you're building a project called SpokaneApp, you'll have a class called SpokaneAppDelegate created for you. You can add code to the applicationDidFinishLaunching method of that class to do custom application logic.

Comment: Thanks guys.. what's the difference between "applicationDidFinishLaunching" and "applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions"?

Comment: From the UIApplicationDelegate Protocol reference (learn to the love the Apple developer documentation):

If your application was launched by the system for a specific reason, the launchOptions dictionary contains data indicating the reason for the launch.

Objects that are not the application delegate can access the same launchOptions dictionary values by observing the notification named UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification and accessing the notification’s userInfo dictionary. That notification is sent shortly after this method returns.

Comment: More information is available here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html